# Load a plist file intro tableview from URL

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am trying to load a plist file called "news.plist" from internet , I would be grateful  if you suggest me some hints .

This code load plist from application :

```
NSString *myfile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"url" ofType:@"plist"];
    titles = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myfile];
```

but instead of `pathForResource` would load from an url like that :
http://example.com/news.plist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:url]`

Comment: thank you it worked ! but I dont know why after lunching , the table will be update , but after scrolling  it crashes !

Comment: @Mc.Lover for class methods you need to retain.  do `[[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:url] retain]`. I believe this(not retaining) should be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
NSURL *nsurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@url];
titles = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:nsurl];
```

Docs are at [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURL)